# On initiating I²C communication, status register SR1 gets reset immediatelly

Tags: stm32, i2c

With the following code to handshake an EEPROM

```
 STM_enableRCCAPB1PeriphClock( RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE );
 STM_resetRCCAPB1PeriphCmd( RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, DISABLE );
 I2C_Cmd( m_pEE_I2C_TYPE, ENABLE );
 I2C_ITConfig( m_pEE_I2C_TYPE, I2C_IT_ERR, ENABLE );
 I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Mode        = EE_I2C_MODE;
 I2C_InitStructure.I2C_DutyCycle      = EE_I2C_DUTY_CYCLE;
 I2C_InitStructure.I2C_OwnAddress1     = EE_I2C_OWN_ADDRESS;
 I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Ack         = EE_I2C_ACK;
 I2C_InitStructure.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = EE_I2C_ACK_ADDR;
 I2C_InitStructure.I2C_ClockSpeed     = EE_I2C_CLOCK_SPEED;
 GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin   = GPIO_Pin_6 BITOR GPIO_Pin_7;
 GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed  = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
 GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode  = GPIO_Mode_AF_OD;


  /* Generate the START condition */
  I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START;

  /* wait until START condition is set */
  while ( NOT ( I2C1->SR1  BITAND  I2C_SR1_SB ) )
  {
  }

  /* send the address of the EEPROM with r/w-bit reset */
  address = EE_EXT_ADDRESS;
  address |= 1u; // read / receiver
  I2C1->DR = address;

  /* wait for either ADDR (ACK) oder AF (NACK) to be set */
  u16StatusRegister = 0x00u;
  while ( NOT ( ( u16StatusRegister  BITAND  I2C_SR1_ADDR )  BITOR  ( 
u16StatusRegister  BITAND  I2C_SR1_AF ) ) )
  {
    u16StatusRegister = I2C1->SR1;
  }
```

I see the rising of either AF or ADDR in the debugger's register view after executing
I2C1->DR = address, but as soon as I execute u16StatusRegister = 0x00u, all bits in SR1 are reset.

Could anybody guess why that's happening?

I'm using IAR workbench 7.50 and IAR I-jets debugger on a STM32f103, and there are no interrupt routines coded.

---

I re-coded it a bit:

```
 /* Generate the START condition */

 I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START;



 /* wait until START condition is set */

 while ( NOT ( I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB ) ) { }



 /* send the address of the EEPROM with r/w-bit reset */

 address = EE_EXT_ADDRESS | 1u; // read / receiver     

 I2C1->DR = address;          



 /* wait for either ADDR (ACK) oder AF (NACK) to be set */

 u8Timeout = MaxWaitForACK;

 while ( ! ( ( I2C1->SR1 & ( I2C_SR1_AF | I2C_SR1_ADDR | I2C_SR1_BTF | I2C_SR1_TXE | I2C_SR1_RXNE ) ) || ( u8Timeout == 0u ) ) ) {

     u8Timeout--;

 }



 if ( I2C1->SR1 & ( I2C_SR1_ADDR | I2C_SR1_BTF | I2C_SR1_TXE | I2C_SR1_RXNE ) ) {

     /* BTF set <-- EEPROM send ACK */ /* ADDR set <-- EEPROM send ACK */

     bRetVal = TRUE;

 }

 else {

     /* BTF not set <-- Timeout <-- EEPROM send NACK */ /* AF set <-- NACK read */

     bRetVal = FALSE;

 }
```

This works always (single step, debugging context, and live) in the case the EEPROM is missing, but in the case the EEPROM exists, it only works when stepping or debugging, not live.

And even more curious: when breaking after the evaluation, see AF set in the fail case, which I don't do when stepping through.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Most bits in status register SR1 will get cleared when they have been set to 1 and the MCU reads them as being set to 1, so you don't have to do anything at all to clear them. This behaviour is explained in the manual.

Comment: Thanks.
But I used the same config in another pice of code in the same software an there I could read this bit before they were reset.

Additionally, this code is from a "how to mplement I²C"-tutorial and ist expected that you have to wait for this bits to be sets.
How can I implement reading them in that case?

Comment: No, sorry, that's not it.
even without a debugger the behavior is still the same.

On a further note, when ADDR gets reset in an read access, BTF and RxNE get set and stay set even after many reads of SR1.

Comment: I said most. Not all.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (as I struggled with it for a while myself):

> Note: Reading I2C_SR2 after reading I2C_SR1 clears the ADDR flag, even
> if the ADDR flag was set after reading I2C_SR1. Consequently, I2C_SR2
> must be read only when ADDR is found set in I2C_SR1 or when the STOPF
> bit is cleared.

This happens when you use the debugger and try to see which bits are set. The debugger reads those registers and with this action it resets the ADDR flag. The AF flag should not be reset by this however. But that indicates an error.

So if you are debugging your code in the I²C section, do not use the debugger to view the I²C registers at the same time (or only when you are sure that no flag will be reset which your code cares about.

Comment: <facepalm> Of course, that's the way this could happen
It doesn't apply to the other code, though, but here it might be the case.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not it. even without a debugger the behavior is still the same. On a further note, when ADDR gets reset in a read access, BTF and RxNE get set and stay set even after many reads of SR1; and if I'm using wrtite access, its only TxE (and TRA on SR2) which stay set.

Comment: @KnutS. I'm not quite sure I understand correctly - when `ADDR` gets set, you are supposed to advance to the next step of your transmission, which is either reading something (that's why `RXnE` is set) or write something (`TxE` set) from or into the `DR` register. Reading the `SR1` will not clear those bits.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand it and what I#m trying to do. But those bits are reset before I can read them; I only see them set when stepping through the code. I see ADDR (or AF) set just as after I've written DR, but with the very next action I take I see it (in the IDEs register view) being reset again. But I expect them to say set until I reinit den I²C Master or read SR1 & SR2.

Comment: @KnutS. okay, as you have checked that it also happens without the debugger (and the register view), I'm a bit lost right now why the bits might get reset without anyone reading the status registers. Just a dumb suggestion: instead of `u16StatusRegister = 0x00u;` read the `SR1` directly.

Comment: using  while ( NOT ( ( ( I2C1->SR1 )  BITAND  I2C_SR1_ADDR )  BITOR  ( ( ( I2C1->SR1 ) BITAND  I2C_SR1_AF ) ) ) ) with Af / ADDR set in the register view enters the while-loop and stays there forever.